# "undefined" returned using Typeahead

Tags: jquery, json, typeahead.js

I'm building an autocomplete function for my app in Symfony2 using Typeahead. When text is entered to the text area, suggestions are returned but they are all displayed as "undefined".

The JSON output is like this:

```
[{"name":"Test"},{"name":"Something"},{"name":"Another thing"},{"name":"Time"}]
```

My HTML & JQuery is this:

```
<h1>Ajax Test</h1>
<div id="prefetch">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Countries">
</div>
<script>
    var countries = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    prefetch: {
    url: 'http://localhost/centredb/web/app_dev.php/centre/dashboard/ajax/centres/',
    filter: function(response){
        return response.Name
    }
    }
    });

    // kicks off the loading/processing of `local` and `prefetch`
    countries.initialize();

    // passing in `null` for the `options` arguments will result in the default
    // options being used
    $('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'countries',
    displayKey: 'name',
    // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
    // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
    source: countries.ttAdapter()
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:**
After looking at a lot of examples, the JSON output is correct, so I have removed the reference to Symfony2. This is strictly an issue with Typeahead using the JSON output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your filter function so that it returns an array of datums (i.e. suggestions). A [datum is a javascript object](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#datums) so you need to generate a javascript object array using the filter function.

You can do so using this:

```
filter: function (centres) {
 return $.map(centres, function (centre) {
  return {
   name: centre.name
  };
 });
}
```

A similar example can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/e7qM9/